# Undefined Index, invalid input syntax for integer errors in HTML-PHP-PDO-PostgreSQL based forms data insertion

Tags: php, html, postgresql, pdo

I am working on a web page to insert data into postgresql database using php-pdo. I am able to successfully insert data into the tables but following notices and one error is raised.

Here are my questions?

1) What wrong I am doing that is causing these errors & warnings ?

2) How to correct errors & warnings?

Here are errors:

**ERRORS**

```
Notice: Undefined index: l_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\ubicomp\index3.php on line 97

Notice: Undefined index: time in C:\xampp\htdocs\ubicomp\index3.php on line 97

Notice: Undefined index: m_gps in C:\xampp\htdocs\ubicomp\index3.php on line 97
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "" LINE 2: VALUES ('','01','','') ^
```

Here is my code:

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PHP-PostgreSQL</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
            <h2 style="color:navy;">PHP - Postgres</h2>

                <?php

                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "postgres";
                $password = "test123";
                $dbname = "testDB";

                class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
                function __construct($it) {
                parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
                }

                    function current() {
                        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
                    }

                        function beginChildren() {
                        echo "<tr>";
                    }   

                        function endChildren() {
                        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
                    }
                    }
                ?>


                <div class="col-sm" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">

                 <?php

                    echo "<h3>Table1</h3>";
                    echo "<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-reponsive'>";
                    echo "<thead class='table-dark'>";
                    echo "<tr><th>l_id</th><th>p_id<th>time</th><th>m_gps</th></tr>";

                        try {
                            $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT l_id, p_id, time, m_gps FROM table1");
                            $stmt->execute();

                        // set the resulting array to associative
                            $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
                                        echo $v;
                                }
                            }
                        catch(PDOException $e) {
                            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                            }
                                //$conn = null;
                                echo "</thead'>";
                                echo "</table>";
                            ?>

                        <div id="form">
                                <form action="" method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="l_id" id="l_id" required="required" placeholder="Enter l_id"/>
                                <input type="text" name="p_id" id="p_id" required="required" placeholder="Enter p_id"/>
                                <input type="text" name="time" id="time" required="required" placeholder="Enter time"/>
                                <input type="text" name="m_gps" id="m_gps" required="required" placeholder="Enter M_gps"/>
                                <br/><br />

                                <input type="submit" value=" Insert " name="submit"/><br />

                                </form>
                            <hr/>
                        </div>

                    <?php

                    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

                        try {
                            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (l_id, p_id, time, m_gps)
                            VALUES ('".$_POST["l_id"]."','".$_POST["p_id"]."','".$_POST["time"]."','".$_POST["m_gps"]."')";

                            if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                            echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
                            }

                            else{
                                echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
                                }

                            $dbh = null;
                            }
                            catch(PDOException $e)
                            {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                            }

                            }   

                        ?>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
                    <?php
                        echo "<h3>Table2</h3>";
                        echo "<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-reponsive'>";
                        echo "<thead class='table-dark'>";
                        echo "<tr><th>a_id</th><th>p_id</th><th>gps_koordinat<th>temp</th></tr>";

                            try {
                                $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT a_id, p_id, gps_koordinaat, temp FROM table2");
                                $stmt->execute();

                            // set the resulting array to associative
                                $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
                                        echo $v;
                                    }
                                }
                            catch(PDOException $e) {
                                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                                            }       
                                //$conn = null;
                                echo "</thead'>";
                                echo "</table>";
                            ?>

                        <div id="form">
                                <form action="" method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="a_id" id="a_id" required="required" placeholder="Enter a_id"/>
                                <input type="text" name="p_id" id="p_id" required="required" placeholder="Enter p_id"/>
                                <input type="text" name="gps_koordinaat" id="gps_koordinaat" required="required" placeholder="Enter gps_koordinaat"/>
                                <input type="text" name="temp" id="temp" required="required" placeholder="Enter temp"/>
                                <br/><br />
                                <input type="submit" value=" Insert " name="submit"/><br />
                            </form>
                                <hr/>
                            </div>

                        <?php

                        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                            try {
                                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                                $sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (a_id, p_id, gps_koordinaat, temp)
                                VALUES ('".$_POST["a_id"]."','".$_POST["p_id"]."','".$_POST["gps_koordinaat"]."','".$_POST["temp"]."')";

                                if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                                echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
                                }   

                                $dbh = null;
                                }
                            catch(PDOException $e)
                                {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                                }

                                }   

                    $conn = null;

                    ?>

                      </div>

                </div>


        </div>

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here are the queries for the tables.

```
**Table1**
CREATE TABLE public.table1
(
    l_id integer NOT NULL,
    p_id integer,
    time text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    m_gps text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT l_pkey PRIMARY KEY (l_id),
    CONSTRAINT table1_p_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (p_id)
        REFERENCES public.table_p (p_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.table1
    OWNER to postgres;
```

**Table2:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.table2
(
    a_id integer NOT NULL,
    p_id integer,
    gps_koordinaat text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    temp real,
    CONSTRAINT a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (a_id),
    CONSTRAINT table2_p_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (p_id)
        REFERENCES public.table_p (p_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.table2
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have tow form with the same name for the submit button, and you have the same control statement for trying to insert in both table.

So you should change the name of one of your button

```
<input type="submit" value=" Insert " name="submit"/>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value=" Insert " name="submit2"/>
```

then change your control of the right form

```
if(isset($_POST["submit2"])){
```

and it should don't remove your undifined index warning !

for the error bring by SQLSTATE it surely because '01' is not recognize as an integer for postgreSQL

Comment: Thank you very much :)
Can you please see why 'echo"<thead class='table-dark'>' is not working.

Comment: i'm not really confident with CSS, but i guess either the class should be on the table instead of the thead, or bs 3.3 didn't have table-dark